# squirrelmail postfixadmin plugin - failed login to xmlrpc instance

Tags: php, squirrelmail, xmlrpc

I have installed postfixadmin 2.3.6 and im using squirrelmail vacation plugin. Postfixadmin is working good i can add/edit/delete email accounts and vacation or forwards / aliases. I have problems with xmlrpc on squirrelmail plugin.

I already configured as below:

**postfixadmin config.inc.php**

```
$CONF['xmlrpc_enabled'] = true;
$CONF['vacation'] = 'YES';
$CONF['vacation_control'] ='YES';
$CONF['vacation_control_admin'] = 'YES';
```

**on postfixadmin squirrelmail config**

```
global $AllowVacation;
$AllowVacation = true;
```

**and YES i have correct URL**

```
$CONF['xmlrpc_url'] = 'http://my-domain/xmlrpc.php';
```

I'm using PHP 5.3 with xmlrpc module already installed, zendframework1 but when I'm login to squirrelmail and then to vacation i can put password but then I got

```
Failed to login to xmlrpc instance
```

**this is apache2 error log of virtual where squirrelmail exist**

```
[Sun Mar 09 16:31:47 2014] [error] [client my-ip] PHP 2. get_xmlrpc() 
/home/squirrelmail/plugins/postfixadmin/postfixadmin_vacation.php:5, referer: 
https://my-domain/plugins/postfixadmin/postfixadmin_vacation.php
[Sun Mar 09 16:31:47 2014] [error] [client my-ip] Failed to login to xmlrpc instance - ,referer: 
https://mydomain/plugins/postfixadmin/postfixadmin_vacation.php
```

I have squirrelmail and postfixadmin where is xmlrpc.php on two separate domains but on same server

```
https://domain/squirrelmail
http://domain2/postfixadmin
```

I don't know what can be wrong, I was trying everything :) maybe some of You have same problems and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is quite old, but still current.

1. Your error message isn't complete:

   Failed to login to xmlrpc instance - ,

Should be extended with the error itself. For example what I (still) have:

```
Failed to login to xmlrpc instance - Unable to Connect to ssl://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:443. Error #0
```

How to do that: change functions.php in /usr/share/squirrelmail/plugins/postfixadmin/functions.inc.php the function need () at the end to get the errormessage

```
error_log("Failed to login to xmlrpc instance - " . $e->getMessage);
```

into

```
error_log("Failed to login to xmlrpc instance - " . $e->getMessage());
```

To be clear: this isnt the solution but at least you know what IS the error. I am still working on this one, in my case it has something to do with ssl: and certificates in the xmlrpc connection.

2. postfixadmin 2.3.7 is out with some bugs solved. 3 items concern vacation. So upgrade to 2.3.7
3. Don't forget to copy vacation.pl from the postfixadmin distribution /VIRTUAL_VACATION/ and make the configuration in that file.